# Porcentagem no resultado

Tags: python, porcentagem

Estou fazendo um menu no Python e preciso que o resultado de uma conta apareça em porcentagem.... O `Tmar` tem valor 2 e `Tcliclo` tem valor 7 sendo o resultado: 0,29 porem não consigo coloca-lo em 29%. Alguem poderia me auxiliar? Obrigada

```
def Calc3 (self,event):

    try:
        TMAR=float(self.TMAR.get())
        TCICLO=float(self.TCICLO.get())
        Result3=((TMAR/TCICLO)*100)
        s="O Indíce de Rotatividade é de   "
        s=s+str(Result3)
       # print (CTP)
    except:
        s="Erro"
    self.txtCALC3['text']=s
    self.TMAR.delete(0, 'end')
    self.TCICLO.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida. O que deveria acontecer e o que acontece de fato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código está correto. Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AUYwAE).

Para o arredondamento do resultado, você pode utilizar o `round()`, desta maneira:

```
s+=str(round(Result3))+"%"
```

E para o escrever o resultado:

```
print (s) #Normalmente.
```

Comment: Muitoooooo obrigada Francisco!!!! Agora apareceu o 29% Obrigada